# Fill first NaN in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input dataframe as

```
ID  Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit1Int4  Visit15
1   Orange              
2   Orange  Apple   
3   Grapes  
4   Apple   
5   Orange Apple    
6   Apple  
7   Banana  
8   Banana  Apple   Banana  Apple   Banana
```

I want to fill the first NA of each row with 'Exit' (SO for ID 1, Visit12 should be 'Exit', for ID2 Visit13 should be 'Exit', etc.). The final output should look like

```
ID  Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit1Int4  Visit15
1   Orange  Exit            
2   Orange  Apple   Exit         
3   Grapes  Exit            
4   Apple   Exit            
5   Orange Apple    Exit       
6   Apple  Exit             
7   Banana  Exit            
8   Banana  Apple   Banana  Apple   Banana E
```

Comment: you need to create last column too for exit entry? like in example there is need of Visit16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start by replacing empty values with `np.nan`, and take the `cumsum` of [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html). Then use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign `Exit` where `cumsum` is `1`, or the value in `df` otherwise:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.replace('',np.nan).isna().cumsum(axis=1)
r = np.where(m == 1, 'Exit', df)
pd.DataFrame(r, columns=df.columns).fillna('')

   ID  Visit11 Visit12 Visit13 Visit1Int4 Visit15
0   1  Orange    Exit                           
1   2  Orange   Apple    Exit                   
2   3  Grapes    Exit                           
3   4   Apple    Exit                           
4   5  Orange   Apple    Exit                   
5   6   Apple    Exit                           
6   7  Banana    Exit                           
7   8  Banana   Apple  Banana      Apple  Banana
```

Comment: To make the problem complicated now i have data set recording 2 visits. The visits may go upto n time depending on the data captured. How do i put exit at the end of each visit.

Comment: `shreeja7` this is a different question which would lead to quite a different solution... I'd suggest you ask this in a new question and you'll surely get it answered